# mysql has table name case sensitive with efcore

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core

Our mysql database was on Tencent Cloud before,
Now we have created one in k8s.
Then our program reported an error means "Table packagedb_dev.ShopOrder" doesn't exist;
Our table name is lowercase.
When I change the table name to uppercase, the error disappears.
I have been using EFcore and mysql for a long time and have never encountered this error.
The orm is EntityframeworkCore,Version: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.9

Comment: Please check your mysql database, ensure that the ShopOrder table exists.

Comment: You also need check the connetionstring in your project.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem.
The cause is that the self-built database is case-sensitive and the database in the container can be cumbersome to set this parameter.